# How to maintain average function in flask with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, html, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have a table ratings, books and users created as follows:

```
    CREATE TABLE books(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ISBN VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  author VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  publicationYear INTEGER NOT NULL
);

    CREATE TABLE ratings(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
  book_id INTEGER REFERENCES books(id),
  rating INTEGER CHECK (rating <= 5)
);

CREATE TABLE users(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR UNIQUE,
  password VARCHAR NOT NULL,
);
```

I tried to make a website where I can rate a particular book, which in turn should maintain its average rating each time some user rates this book. 
My attempt: in application.py under some route:
....

```
rating = db.execute("SELECT AVG(rating) FROM ratings WHERE book_id = :id", {"id": book_id}).fetchone()
    if rating is None:
        rating = 0
....
return render_template("details.html", rating = rating, book = book)
```

Inside details.html:

```
(some html code)
Rating: {{ rating }} out of 5
(some other html code)
```

Everything works fine (no errors whatsoever), but there are two issues I couldn't solve:

1) If no ratings are made, I expected web-site to display 0 (rating), but it showed "(None,)" instead.

2) If there are ratings, instead of showing (for example) 4.5 as rating(I want the answer to be rounded to 1 decimal place), it displays "(Decimal('4.5000000000000000'),)"

How to fix these problems and why it retrieves something other than float (I'm assuming because rating has some other type other than integer)?

Remark: I can't use any stuff like creating classes/objects or special SQLAlchemy properties - only SQL queries like the ones above.

Comment: hello Afar, welcome to stackoverflow. Can you print rating just before you return the rendered view? This doesnt seem closely related to SQLAlchemy, and I dont really see a mistake in that part.
you could check if 
    round(rating,1)
does the trick

Answer (score 1):

There are some possible fixes for your problems you could try:

I suspect sqlalchemy doesnt return any rows if there isnt a rating, but its not "None", but rather an empty array [], or an sql result with rowcount 0

try this check instead:

```
if not rating:
  rating = 0
```

or

```
for item in rating:
  if item is None:
     rating = 0
```

Python does a lot of checks for falsy (zero, empty arrays, None, etc...), however if you specifically say "is None", you're only checking for exactly None. Print the rating after your execute to check out what exactly is going on there.

similarly, if you do get a rating, you should print it out and see what the number looks like. Its probably very easy to fix, so try `round(number,1)`, which removes all the decimals except 1.

Make sure you work with an IDE that allows you to set breakpoints and inspect code while it happens. Printing everything out isnt viable in the long run.